# How to use C# to access Apex REST Service

Tags: apex, rest

I want to use C# to access my own apex rest service in a managed package. I can easily do it in IOS and Android. But in C# I wrote code below, it can not work.

```
string restQuery = App._instanceUrl + @"/services/apexrest/namespace/myservice";  
string requestMessage = "Account,Contact";  

HttpContent content = new StringContent(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestMessage)));

HttpClient queryClient = new HttpClient();

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, restQuery);  
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth " + App._accessToken);  
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));  
request.Content = content;  

HttpResponseMessage response = await queryClient.SendAsync(request);  
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();  
string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the error you are receiving ?

Comment: There is only 401 error received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue, The request param must be a json format.

```
//joining together the json format string sample:"{"key":"valus"}";
string requestMessage = "{\"jsonData\":\"" + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Account,Contact")) + "\"}";

HttpContent content = new StringContent(requestMessage, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

//create url using package name in URL
string restQuery = App._instanceUrl +@"/services/apexrest/namespace/MyService";

//create request message associated with POST verb
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, restQuery);

//return JSON to the caller
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

//add token to header
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + App._accessToken);

//add content to HttpRequestMessage;
request.Content = content;

HttpClient putClient = new HttpClient();

//call endpoint async
HttpResponseMessage response = await putClient.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: HI, Did you have to create a connected App before you could connect to your apex web service ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [Force.com Toolkit for .NET](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET) as a reference. There are a couple of tutorials which may be useful as well.

[Working with Custom SOAP and REST Services in .NET Applications](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Working_with_Custom_SOAP_and_REST_Services_in_.NET_Applications)

[Consuming Force.com SOAP and REST Web Services from .NET Applications](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Consuming_Force.com_SOAP_and_REST_Web_Services_from_.NET_Applications)

If you are running into a 401, there's a good chance that your access token has expired. Refresh your access token and try again

Comment: Yes, I checked Force.com Toolkit for .NET，It seems only standard GRUD operation, don't have a custom apex rest call example.  

In other two links I found the demo code is the same with mine. But why my code can't work?

Comment: Updated answer, you should check for access token validity

Comment: Your authorization header looks different than mine.  My header appears in curl as:  "Authorization: Bearer 00DM0000001dSYq!ARAAQF1xqLq6o8cNEJ7VHxqaaRkNQlJoApQFuMbkpBLcPkC4szoxo7m6oMomen2TRIfqF20kErjhYy9ew5Aq1gc4Y8goaXUo".

Note the "Bearer" before the token.

Comment: I have tried to use  "Bearer", but it still can't  work.