# How to use the apexrest with C#

Tags: webservices, php, c#, apexrest

I developed a code to generate Accounts from the web in PHP but now I'm in front of a chlange to make it in C# for an emergency here is my PHP code, if you can help me how to do it ..... many thx

```
<------

https://xxx.secure.force.com/services/apexrest/Accounts

        $tab = array(
            'firstname'=> $prenom,  
            'lastname'=>  $nom,
            'personemail' => $email_a,
            'phone' => $tel,
            );

            print_r($tab);
            $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($tab),
            ),
        );
        $context  = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

        var_dump($result);

        $message = $result; 

        echo $result;
---->
```

Answer (score 2):

A [.NET tool kit](http://www.wadewegner.com/2014/01/announcing-the-salesforce-toolkits-for-net/) was announced by salesforce.

"The Force.com Toolkit for .NET provides an easy way for .NET developers to interact with the Force.com REST API using a native libraries."

https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/

Check this [tutorial](http://danlb.blogspot.com/2010/10/salesforcecom-rest-api.html) as well

For custom webservice [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63088/how-to-use-c-to-access-apex-rest-service) may help you as well

Comment: I have downloaded this Force.com toolkit from above mentioned github link, it has sample folder when opening one of the sample project I can see missing toolkit reference in project, from where I can add them as when I browse through the assembles I am not able to find any dll naming these.